# Is it possible to use symfony translations internally in vue js?

Tags: symfony, vue.js, templates, localization, translation

I have Symfony 4.4 application with localization on different languages `translations/*.yml`.

For example in `translations/messages.en.yml`

```
site:
    name: My site
```

So in my twig templates, I can use

```
{{ 'site.name'|trans }}
```

I started to use Vue js for my front (with WebBack and Symfony Encore).
I know that Vue js has its own internationalization in JSON format.
But I don't want to duplicate my translation twice...

**Question**
Is it possible use Symfony translations in some way in Vue JS?
Something like that...

```
<template>
    <h2>My Vue template</h2>
    {{ 'site.name|trans }}
</template>
```

**Question2**
Is it possible to use `x` variable inside of vue template ?

```
    /**
     * @Route("", name="homepage")
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    function homepage()
    {
        return $this->render(
            'index.html.twig', [
                'x' => 'test',
            ]
        );
    }
```

Vue template

```
<template>
    <h2>My Vue template</h2>
    {{ x }}
</template>
```

Appreciate any advice

Answer (score 1):

Getting Symfony translations into JS is a bit tricky. Theoretically you could get the catalog as a template variable and then assign it to a JS-variable, but with a large catalog that will be quite a lot of overhead, plus you will expose your translation labels, which might leak unwanted infos about variables, but for smaller projects I find this to be the easiest solution:

```php
# Controller
public function index(TranslatorInterface $translator)
{
    return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
        'translation_catalog' => $translator->getCatalogue($locale),
    ]);
}
```

The method `getCatalogue()` is not part of the interface, but is provided by Symfony's translator. You might have to add a type hint for your IDE to recognize it.

```
# twig-template
{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const translations = {{ translation_catalog|json_encode }}
    </script>
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

The `{{ translations|json_encode }}` will take your catalogue and transform it into a JSON-object. You should then be able to access translations in vue by accessing this object.

Another solution could be, to create an API endpoint which gives you the translations for a key. I find this suboptimal as you will perform lots of HTTP requests for translations which is bad for performance and you will still have the downside of exposing your translation labels with each API call. I would strongly advise against this approach.

A better solution would be to have your translations in a format that both Symfony's translation component and JS/vue will understand. Then you can simply reuse the translation files.

In modern Symfony (4.2+) this should be easier as the translator supports [ICU format](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/translation/message_format.html), which is also supported by JS libs, e.g. [Format.js](https://formatjs.io/) (there might be vue integrations for this library out there, but I am not familiar with them, so I can't recommend any). This allows you to directly import your translation files in JS, bypassing your Symfony application, but still use the same files as Symfony. Your build tool can then be used to only keep those keys you actually need in your JS code or you generate static files for each language and not rely on the original, static translation files at all during runtime.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @dbrumann ! 

Good idea, really easy to use.   
But I have more than 100 controllers..    
Now I m thinking about generating full HTML (from twig) in controller and get it with Vue.

Something like that
`
public function index(TranslatorInterface $translator)
{
    return $this->render('section.html.twig');
}
`   
and get it with Vue js.
I don't know is this really bad practice for vue.
In this case vue even should not know about locale.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

well, we've done this. but as @dbrumann stated, it's really tricky, but it works.

1. create a route/controller, in which you dump translations via `getCatalogue` into json
2. in vue, store the json response of this controller into [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). issue this request **only** when session storage variable does not exist.
3. hook into vue i18n to fetch translations from the local storage variable
4. profit

there are some caveats though, which you need to resolve in some way:

1. updating translations. if you request them only when session storage variable is not present, then they don't get updated. so, apply some sort of lifetime or versioning mechanism.
2. translations key + translation domain. you need to transform these in that dumping controller into something like `domain.flattened.translation.key`

but it is more effective than including them into a js var in every response.